# SQLzoo Music Tutorial item 4: left join or inner join?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I was doing the SQLzoo Music Tutorial Question 4, which can be found here (https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Music_Tutorial). I am not sure whether I should use `left join` or `inner join`

The problem asks "For each `album` show the `title` and the total number of `track`."

I found that the "correct" solution to this problem is

```
select A.title, count(T.song)
from album as A inner join track as T
on A.asin = T.album
group by A.title
```

But I feel that based on this question, the solution should be

```
select A.title, count(T.song)
from album as A left join track as T
on A.asin = T.album
group by A.title
```

Because, there could be (and indeed there are in this question) album title in the `album` table that have no corresponds in the `track` table. And using

```
select A.title, count(T.song)
from album as A left join track as T
on A.asin = T.album
group by A.title
having count(T.song) = 0
```

I found that

```
title           count(T.song)
A Love Supreme        0
The Hits              0
```

these two album do not have correspondence in the `Track` table.

Comment: Use left join then if you need to show the albums that 0 total number of tracks, otherwise use inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Here are asin & title for albums whose asin is not an album in track:

```
select A.asin, A.title
from album A left join track T
on A.asin = T.album
where T.album is null
```

```
asin        title
B000003N7A  Love Supreme
B000008O4G  The Hits
```

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Was there a problem why you did not want to upvote?